# C# Windowsform - How made this code better (runtime created textbox and label) change too many ifs to repetition structure

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, textbox, runtime

i have code that its working but its not as i would like.

in runtime i create many new textbox/labels so i had to use 10 ifs to check each "future" textbox have textlength = 0 and != null

i would like to use repeat structure like for or while, dont know if its possible.

For example, if i create more textbox/labels will be impossible have really big code.

See my code:

```
private void cadeiaapagarcampos(TextBox _text, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (_text.Text == "")
            {
                Label lblAcessorio2 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio2", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio2 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio2", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio3 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio3", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio3 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio3", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio4 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio4", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio4 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio4", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio5 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio5", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio5 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio5", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio6 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio6", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio6 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio6", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio7 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio7", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio7 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio7", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio8 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio8", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio8 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio8", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio9 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio9", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio9 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio9", false).FirstOrDefault();
                Label lblAcessorio10 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio10", false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio10 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio10", false).FirstOrDefault();

                if (txtAcessorio2 != null && txtAcessorio2.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio2);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio2);
                    btnSalvar.Focus();
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }                    
                }
                if (txtAcessorio3 != null && txtAcessorio3.TextLength == 0)
                {

                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio3);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio3);
                    btnSalvar.Focus();
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtAcessorio4 != null && txtAcessorio4.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio4);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio4);
                    btnSalvar.Focus();
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtAcessorio5 != null && txtAcessorio5.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio5);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio5);
                    btnSalvar.Focus();
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtAcessorio6 != null && txtAcessorio6.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio6);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio6);
                    btnSalvar.Focus(); 
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtAcessorio7 != null && txtAcessorio7.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio7);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio7);
                    btnSalvar.Focus(); 
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtAcessorio8 != null && txtAcessorio8.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio8);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio8);
                    btnSalvar.Focus();
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtAcessorio9 != null && txtAcessorio9.TextLength == 0)
                {
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio9);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio9);
                    btnSalvar.Focus();
                    if (test != 1)
                    {
                        n--;
                        t++;
                        if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                        {
                            testeapagar();
                            test = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be what you are looking for? If you have more labels just update iAcessorioContar and it will automatically check them as well as long as you name the labels incrementally.

```
private void cadeiaapagarcampos(TextBox _text, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_text.Text == "")
            {
                int iAcessorioContar = 10;
                for (int iContador = 2; iContador <= iAcessorioContar; iContador++) {
                    Label lblAcessorio = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio"+iContador, false).FirstOrDefault();
                    TextBox txtAcessorio = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio"+iContador, false).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (txtAcessorio != null && txtAcessorio.TextLength == 0)
                    {
                        gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(txtAcessorio);
                        gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(lblAcessorio);
                        btnSalvar.Focus();
                        if (test != 1) {
                            n--;
                            t++;
                            if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
                            {
                                testeapagar();
                                test = 1;
                            }
                        }                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Really thaks for that you was awesome +1000 it really will make things more easy and better, will use this syntax in too many codes that i have. Are you from brazil ? You use variable: iAcessorioContar (portugues), caso seja, muito obrigado !

Comment: De nada! I'm glad it helped, building your code like this makes things much more dynamic. You can improve it by incrementing iAcessorioContar by 1 every time you create a control or decrementing when you remove a control so you don't have to update it yourself every time. I'm not from Brazil, but I know a couple of words (Or atleast I think I do) and thought I should conform to the language used.

Comment: Thanks again, made it, n variable that already is in my code is variable that know if have 1 to 10 text box, so i replaced 10 for n and it work great, this way it avoid unnecessary loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the controls in pairs (label and textbox) to a list when you create them so you do not have to search the controls collection which can cost a lot of time.

You can then simply loop the list.